# creating a message in MSMQ from Mule

Tags: java, msmq, mule

I am using a java class as a mule endpoint that writes a message into a windows message queue.  This is being done to "glue" a java app with a .Net app that consumes the data.

I am using the ionic msmq libraries

I intermittently get a message queue exception

"*message queue exception: Cannot open queue. (hr=unknown hr (-2))*"

The queue exists and permissions are correct.

Anyone throw any light on what this error means or know of reliable ways of writing to message queues from java/mule?

Comment: What is the code doing when the exception is raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception looks like it might be coming from ionic. doesnt' look like a mule exception.

Specifically to MSMQ, MuleSoft offers and supports a MSMQ specific transport as part of their enterprise subscription. Mule does have strong support for both JMS and AMQP message protocols.